# KeyError: u'somestring' Json

Tags: python, json

I am trying to make a point system for my Twitch bot and I am encountering KeyErrors when trying to make a new entry for some odd reason. Here is my code:

```
import urllib2, json

def updateUsers(chan):
    j = urllib2.urlopen('http://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/' + chan + '/chatters')
    j_obj = json.load(j)
    with open('dat.dat', 'r') as data_file:
        data = json.load(data_file)
    for usr in j_obj['chatters']['viewers']:
        data[usr]['Points'] = "0" # Were the KeyError: u'someguysusername' occurs
    with open('dat.dat', 'w') as out_file:
        json.dump(data, out_file)

updateUsers('tryhard_clan')
```

If you want to see the Json itself go to http://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/tryhard_clan/chatters

I'm storing user data in a file in this format:

```
{"users": {"cupcake": {"Points": "0"}}}
```

Comment: you first have to make a dict for the user, ie `data[usr] = {'Points':'0'}`

Comment: Obviously, this is because there is no `someguysusername` key at the top level in `data`; if you want to create one if it doesn't exist, then you need to actually do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens variable `usr` doesn't resolve to an existing key in `data`. Do this instead:

```
if usr not in data:
    data[usr] = {}
data[usr]['Points'] = "0"
```

Answer (score 2):

a slightly more concise form than @Raunak suggested:

```
data.setdefault (usr, {}) ['Points'] = "0"
```

that will set `data[usr]` to an empty dict if it's not already there, and set the `'Points'` element in any case.